# Panda- How can some column values can be moved to new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data frame

```
d = {
 "name":["RRR","RRR","RRR","RRR","RRR","ZZZ","ZZZ","ZZZ","ZZZ","ZZZ"],
 "id":[1,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,4],"value":[12,13,1,44,22,21,23,53,64,9]
}
```

[image: dataframe]

I want the out output as below:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pivot by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with helper column `ind` by `id`, then sorting second level of `MultiIndex` with flatten values:

```
df = (df.assign(ind = df['id'])
        .set_index(['name','id', df.groupby(['name','id']).cumcount()])[['value', 'ind']]
        .unstack(1)
        .sort_index(axis=1, kind='mergesort', level=1))

df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.droplevel(1).reset_index()
print (df)  

  name  ind_1  value_1  ind_2  value_2  ind_3  value_3  ind_4  value_4
0  RRR    1.0     12.0    2.0      1.0    3.0     22.0    NaN      NaN
1  RRR    1.0     13.0    2.0     44.0    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
2  ZZZ    NaN      NaN    2.0     21.0    3.0     23.0    4.0     64.0
3  ZZZ    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN    3.0     53.0    4.0      9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def func(sub: pd.DataFrame) ->pd.DataFrame:
    dfs = [g.reset_index(drop=True).rename(
        columns=lambda x: f'{x}_{n}') for n, g in sub.drop(columns='name').groupby('id')]
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

res = df.groupby('name').apply(func).droplevel(1).reset_index()
print(res)

>>>
    name    id_1  value_1  id_2  value_2  id_3  value_3  id_4   value_4
0   RRR     1.0   12.0     2.0   1.0      3.0   22.0     NaN    NaN
1   RRR     1.0   13.0     2.0   44.0     NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN
2   ZZZ     NaN   NaN      2.0   21.0     3.0   23.0     4.0    64.0
3   ZZZ     NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN      3.0   53.0     4.0    9.0
```